# EntityManager is always null with @PersistenceContext

Tags: java, jpa, jakarta-ee

I'm using Wildfly to create a simple crud app to manage books (find and persist)

But EntityManager is always returning null.

I tried Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("PU") method, it's working fine.

**I need to know why my code is not working..What is missing or wrong ?**

Thank you

> **Personel level in Jee = beginner**
>
> Wildfly version 14
>
> IDE Intellij
>
> Java 7
>
> JEE 7
>
> ORM EclipseLink

Book.java:

```
package Model;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Book {

    @Id
    private Long id;
    private String title;
    private String description;
    private Float unitCost;
    private String isbn;

    public Book(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Book() {
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public Float getUnitCost() {
        return unitCost;
    }

    public void setUnitCost(Float unitCost) {
        this.unitCost = unitCost;
    }

    public String getIsbn() {
        return isbn;
    }

    public void setIsbn(String isbn) {
        this.isbn = isbn;
    }
}
```

BookService.java

```
package Service;

import Model.Book;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContextType;
import javax.transaction.Transactional;


@Transactional
public class BookService {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "applicationCDBookStorePU", type = PersistenceContextType.EXTENDED)
    private EntityManager em;

    public void persist(Book book) {
        em.persist(book);
    }

    public Book find(long id) {
        return em.find(Book.class, id);
    }
}
```

persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" version="2.0">

    <persistence-unit name="applicationCDBookStorePU" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
        <properties>
            <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost/book"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.driver" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.user" value="postgres"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.password" value="root"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Test main

```
package Service;

public class Test {
    public void displayBook(long id) {
        BookService bookService = new BookService();
        System.out.println(bookService.find(id));
    }
}
```

index.jsp

```
<%@ page import="Service.Test" %><%--
  Created by IntelliJ IDEA.
  Date: 02/04/2019
  Time: 15:07
  To change this template use File | Settings | File Templates.
--%>
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>$Title$</title>
</head>
<body>
    <%
    Test test = new Test();
    test.displayBook(1);
    %>
< /body>
</html>
```

StackTrace:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:473)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:403)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:347)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:791)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:74)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
    at io.undertow.jsp.JspFileHandler.handleRequest(JspFileHandler.java:32)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:68)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:132)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.GlobalRequestControllerHandler.handleRequest(GlobalRequestControllerHandler.java:68)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:292)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:138)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:135)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:272)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:104)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:360)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:830)
    at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1985)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1487)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1378)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Service.BookService.find(BookService.java:22)
    at Service.Test.displayBook(Test.java:6)
    at org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:102)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:791)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:433)
    ... 46 more
```

Code structure: 
[image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vo74b.png)

Answer (score 1):

In order to use a EntityManager injected by `@PersistenceContext` it needs to be managed by your container (Widlfly).

So you must let your container to be in charge of creating those classes with help of `@Inject` annotation.

- To make things easier instead of using JSP files, create a JSF (index.xhtml) like:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">


<h:body>
    Message is: #{test.displayBook(1)}
</h:body>
</html>
```

- Your Test class needs to be annotated with @Named("test") to be accesible from jsf:

**Important:** Make sure you use correct imports.

```
package Service;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;

@Named("test")
public class Test {

    @Inject
    private BookService bookService;

    public String displayBook(long id) {
        bookService.find(id);
        return "Done!";
    }
}
```

- Your BookingService can look like this:

```
package Service;


import Model.Book;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContextType;
import javax.transaction.Transactional;

@Transactional
public class BookService {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "applicationCDBookStorePU", type = PersistenceContextType.EXTENDED)
    private EntityManager em;

    public void persist(Book book) {
        em.persist(book);
    }

    public Book find(long id) {
        System.out.println("EntityManager: " + em.toString());
        return em.find(Book.class, id);
    }

}
```

- Leave your Book model as it is.
- Rearrange folders as shown in following screenshot:

[Project tree structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Hq2l.png)

- Create a beans.xml as shown in picture with following content, this allows CDI (JavaEE dependency injector) to scan for classes.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_1.xsd"
       bean-discovery-mode="all">
</beans>
```

Deploy your application, go to http://localhost:PORT/CONTEXT/index.html

If you see in your wildfly log an entry like:

```
INFO  [stdout] (default task-2) EntityManager: org.jboss.as.jpa.container.TransactionScopedEntityManager@54e9b6cd
```

EntityManager has been injected properly.

**PS:** Following Java naming convention, packages must be lower case to avoid conflict with the names of classes or interfaces https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/namingpkgs.html

**PS2:** Standard Directory Layout for maven project, more info: https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html

Comment: I'm getting "cannot resolve symbol displayBook" in jsp

Comment: You right, I will update my answer with more details. Any inconvenience in change from jsp to jsf?

Comment: @PabloAM How is JSP (or JSF) related to this?

Comment: Not related at all. I am just trying to give a functional example as closest as possible as the owner of the question shows in the question. Thanks.

Comment: I need to know the reason why my code doesn't work....I'm not sure, But I think the persistance annotation (@PersistenceContext) is not looking for the Persistence xml file, and I ignore why !

Comment: @DevJava Have you tried my example above? I have tested myself and entity manager is getting injected. Check your structure project it should be like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Hq2l.png)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add

```
      <class>Model.Book</class>
```

in persistence-unit.